# Where can I find the apk file on my Android phone?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to develop android applications with eclipse (following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html) ). Clicking the 'Run' button inside eclipse (running on Linux) and choosing an android device, `eclipse` tells me that the application is successfully installed on the device.

```
[2014-07-02 19:26:55 - MyFirstApp] Installing MyFirstApp.apk...
[2014-07-02 19:27:01 - MyFirstApp] Success!
[2014-07-02 19:27:02 - MyFirstApp] /MyFirstApp/bin/MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
[2014-07-02 19:27:02 - MyFirstApp] Done!
```

However, I cannot find this application in the list of installed applications on the phone. It only shows up in Settings -> Applications where I am only able to remove it, but not to start it. Maybe I need to do something special in order to let the app show up normally and useable?

As a next step, I installed an 'AppInstaller' to install the apk file. But I do now know which folder on the android phone the apk has been copied to. Where did eclipse put the apk in?

This is in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please post your Manifest too

Comment: "It only shows up in Settings -> Applications" -- that *is* the list of installed applications. "However, I cannot find this application in the list of installed applications on the phone" -- I assume that you mean the home screen launcher. In that case, that is not "the list of installed applications". That is the list of launchable activities published by the installed applications. An application can have zero, one, or more activities flagged with the `<intent-filter>` indicating that they belong in the `LAUNCHER`.

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that you didn't specify a launcher activity in the Manifest.

```
<activity android:name="... >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html):

> - The `ACTION_MAIN` action indicates this is the main entry point and does not expect any intent data.
> - The `CATEGORY_LAUNCHER` category indicates that this activity's icon should be placed in the system's app launcher. If the 
>     element does not specify an icon with icon, then the system uses the
>     icon from the  element.

Comment: Manifest added, I have no idea what laucher activity means.

Comment: Does it mean the tutorial I am following is incorrect/incomplete?

Comment: @Alex Generally, this is added automatically by the IDE when creating a new project and selecting to create a new activity too (that's why the tutorial doesn't mention it). If you're using eclipse with ADT 23, there have been some problems reported, may be related to this.

Comment: Ok I see, that might be the problem. Now it seems eclipse copies the apk to the phone and tries to run it, only that it crashes immediately... I am not surpised...

Comment: The explication about Launcher and Default:

 The LAUNCHER category says that this entry point (Application)should be listed in the application launcher.

 The DEFAULT category is required for the Context.startActivity() method to resolve your activity when its component name is not explicitly specified. 

In resume: Just have 1 Launcher the Main activity and all rest with Default.